# Problem in Integrating TripIt api

Tags: php

I downloaded tripit_php_v1_25392 zip file i try to run the file in my local xamp it asks for api_url, consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token ,access_token_secret keys how do i get those values and run the file

Answer (score 0):

Some of these values are needed to build a OAuth Consumer, [here](http://blog.andydenmark.com/2009/03/how-to-build-oauth-consumer.html) an interesting blog post about it, found via the [API documentation](http://groups.google.com/group/api_tripit/web/tripit-api-documentation---v1#authentication_section)